# Why is $N(A^TA) = N(A)$ right? (N represents null space and A has real entries)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is $"N(A^TA) = N(A)$ when A has real entries" in my textbook.

$N(B) \subseteq N(AB) $ is obvious, but I cannot show that $N(A^TA) = N(A)$ is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A^{T}Ax=0$ implies $\langle A^{T}Ax , x \rangle=0$ which implies $\langle Ax , Ax \rangle =0$ or $\|Ax||^{2}=0$. Hence $Ax=0$  as required.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is a real $n \times n$ - matrix let us denote by $( \cdot, \cdot)$ the usual inner product and by $|| \cdot ||$ the induced norm on $ \mathbb R^n.$

For $x \in \mathbb R^n$ we have

$$(A^TAx,x)=(Ax,Ax)=||Ax||^2.$$

This gives:

$$A^TAx=0 \iff Ax=0.$$